# Confused between Simple Present and Present Progressive

Tags: present-tense, present-progressive, present-continuous

I know that the Present Progressive is used for current events (the action is happening right now) and Simple Present is for express habits.

But, i'm still having trouble to distinguish them.

> For example:
>
> -Where are you going?
>
> -Where do you go?

I think both are correct grammarly. Since there is no frequency adverb or additional senteces such as "every week, every day, right now, in this morning, today, etc.".

When we're talking about sentences without adverb, how to use "be" and "Do/Does" properly?

> Second example: Which one is true? (I'm asking)
>
> -Is he talking to his wife?
>
> -Does he talking to his wife?

The first question sentece is an example on my book, and the second one (i'm not sure about it), anyway i was trying to type the second sentence on google translate in my native language, and it translated as "Does he talking to his wife?".

So who is right? My book or the translator?

Please explain to me with the language that's easy to understand. Thanks.

Comment: It’s just “Does he talk to his wife?”

Comment: We wouldn't use "Where do you go?" to mean "where are you going?". We would only use it of a habitual action - "Where do you go to buy your groceries?"